# Is it possible to show one video at two different places?

Tags: html5-video

I am working on a JS/HTML5 application that has to show the same video in two different places of the screen.

I can use any web browser I want - currently I am with Chrome.

Is it possible to display same video in two different places of the screen, or do I need to setup two different streaming sessions and take care of keeping them in sync?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can use same video src for two video players in the same page**

```
<video width="320" height="240"  controls="controls" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For video player options below is the url

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

and you can test the example

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240"  controls="controls" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

replace the html in w3schools Tryit Editor

Comment: Thanks.
That is a workaround I was thinking of, but it is hard to keep both the vids in sync.